# block ipad camera

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios5, camera

Is there any way in which the usage of the camera of the iPad2 can be restricted only to my application? even if it is using i tunes.

could not find any code related to it. some code would be helpful.

Comment: Good question!  I was going to suggest as an official answer [`[AVCaptureDevice lockForConfiguration:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVCaptureDevice/lockForConfiguration:), but now that I look at it, I think it only locks the settings configuration of the camera and doesn't make the usage exclusive.  You should file a feature request at bugreporter.apple.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to achieve this. I think it could be done with quite a bunch of hacking if you were developing for Cydia, but I'm not sure ever then. If the user quits your application or switches from it, the system will make the camera available to any other app requesting it.